# Close triangle of trapezoidal window (wall uses plaster board and ACC)

Tags: drywall, concrete

I have to replace a big trapezoidal window. The old window goes up to the slope of the roof, but now I want to close the corner part, because it isn't very practical. It looks like this:
[image: Wall and window sketch]

The wall construction is a combination of ACC ([Autoclaved Aerated Concrete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoclaved_aerated_concrete)) and wooden framework, like this:

[image: wall construction]

On top of the window isn't ACC, but only plasterboard on the wooden framing and is about 10cm less thick. So the wall looks like this:

[image: Overall wall construction sketch]

To prepare for the new window I removed the old plaster. This also loosened some small acc bricks, that were between the top and bottom beam. I guess they weren't properly attached anyway, because the top one was hold by construction foam. Now it looks like this:

[image: phtoto of wall with window]

The outside shingles have to be removed anyway. For this reason about 6cm wood fibre insulation boards and slate shingles with some ventialtion space inbetween will be added.

**Now I just have to figure out a way to fix the left and right side of the windows. I'm looking for a solution that solves the following requirements**

- maximizes the rectangular window size
- the closed triangle should be flush with the acc wall below
- minimizing thermal bridges would be benefitial
- Has to allow proper mounting of the new windows (old windows weren't properly mounted)
- avoid cracking, that may appear due to different materials
- easier methods are preferred

I've been thinking about adding vertical beams on the left and right side with some new acc bricks for the triangle. Then maybe use calcium silicate boards or wooden fibre insulation boards for the window reveal, but I'm not sure how to mount them on due to the combination of wood framing and acc.

The water proofness will be archieved by using the correct sealing system for the window (maybe something like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fuBuNzqsjuE).

Comment: I added a Wiki link to AAC for those, like me, who weren't familiar with it.

Comment: Is it just an expanse of yard and street outside this wall, or is there another building nearby?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: I added a lot of information. I'm not sure why you are asking, but there isn't another building nearby

Comment: This is a dramatic improvement in the question quality, but it now invites opinions by asking what's "best". Since you haven't defined what "best" means to you, we have no way of knowing what that means to you. Are you looking for cheapest? Waterproof? Matching existing finishes? More detailed pics of the openings that you're looking to cover would probably be helpful, too.

Comment: @FreeMan: I rewrote the question and added some requirements for a good solution. I'll try to add another photo later

Answer (score 0):

From [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoclaved_aerated_concrete), I quote:

> AAC products may be used for both interior and exterior construction, and may be painted or coated with a *stucco or plaster compound*
> <sup>Emphasis added</sup>

That would lead me to believe that the thermal expansion properties of AAC and plaster are similar enough that there wouldn't be any cause for concern about the coating flaking off due to cracking. Since a skim coat of plaster wouldn't be likely to crack off, I would *assume* that plasterboard/drywall would have similar enough properties to not be of concern.

Disclaimer: This is pure conjecture, but seems reasonable. I have no experience, professional or otherwise, to support this.

---

I would say, though, from further reading of that page, that it seems that AAC units are quite easy to work with, since they can be worked with standard woodworking tools, so you might want to consider filling in the voids with new AAC blocks instead. That would completely eliminate any concerns about dissimilar materials causing cracks.